# Options is not defined : Highchart error, Javascript

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am trying to implement Higcharts in my project,

What I have is a function in which I am defining var `options` of Highcharts so that I can use that `option` variable in the Highchart.

but when I am using that Variable in the Highcharts its displaying the Following error :

> Uncaught ReferenceError: options is not defined

Here's How I tried my code :

```
function data(response){

 var options = {
    // Some Code that goes in option

  }
    }
```

and here's how I anm Calling it ;

```
data(response);
Highcharts.Chart.update(options);
```

I already mentioned what my error is. Please correct me where I am wrong.
Any help is really Appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also return options from the function:

```
var chart = Highcharts.chart('container', {
    series: [{
        data: [1,2,3]
    }]
});

function data(response) {
    var options = {
        series: [{ data: [10, 20, 30] }]
    }

    return options;
}

setTimeout(function(){
    chart.update(data());
}, 1000);
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/fug2x3v4/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Chart#update

Comment: I want this code to work where options is already defined in highchart's function.

http://jsfiddle.net/abnitchauhan/ygshv0Lo/

Comment: Hi @Abnit Chauhan, You can do it in this way: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/2fywa7vg/1/

Answer (score 0):

You have declared the variable inside the function but using it outside the function where you will always get `variable undefined` error. You should create a global variable or in the same scope where you are using it.

```
var options = {};

function data(response){

 options = {
    // Some Code that goes in option
  }
}

data(response);
Highcharts.Chart.update(options);
```